# How to use pretty_midi with UTF-8 encoding？

Tags: python, utf-8, midi

I'm going to use pretty_midi to make a midi file with lyrics(Chinese). But it hints:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u6211' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

How can I solve this problem? Can I change the encoding to utf-8?

Comment: you can search which encoding method chinese characters us, that will solve your problem

Comment: Does pretty_midi support any encoding with Chinese ? I'm afraid the answer is not.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Please also post a link to the pretty_midi documentation. Edit the post with the "edit" button below your post.

Comment: A code example:```import pretty_midi

midi = pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI()
l = pretty_midi.Lyric(text='我',time=0)
midi.lyrics.append(l)

midi.write('test.mid')``` [link](https://craffel.github.io/pretty-midi/#pretty-midi-lyric) is the pretty_midi documentation. Thank you!